# Set default activity, execute before main Activity

Tags: android, manifest, main-activity

I want to make register_activity is first run if application open. But, still MainActivity run first. Can anybody help me to fix this.

This is my Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.client18.dd">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <activity android:name=".register_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".signup_activity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: basing from your `AndroidManifest`, `register_activity` should be called first. Did you happen to interchange your layouts?

Comment: Post some of the register activity. At least the `onCreate()`. Maybe you are doing something funky there

Comment: Maybe you should also follow Java naming conventions. Since it is a class,  should you call it as RegisterActivity instead of register_activity?

Answer (score 0):

When I see your Manifest file I can not see any faults. I suggest to do followings.

1) Uninstall app in emulator / device if its exists, and then run application.

or

2) Rebuild project with cleaning  ( Build > Clean Project )

P.S.

If you could practice **signup_activity > SignupActivity**  it is nice and best practice.